# Faster way to create choices for column in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, modern-experience, choices

I'm currently trying to recreate an old application built in Access in Power apps. This app includes a form with dropdown menu including multiple locations:

Example:

1. location 1
2. location 2
3. location 3
4. etc...

Is there a faster way to add these options to a choice column in a SharePoint list? (as illustrated below)

[image]

As there are many more data sets I have to do this for and I'd much rather not copy and paste all the choices by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on Settings (Gear) icon --> Select **List settings**

   [image]
3. On list settings page, scroll down to **Columns** section
4. Click on your choice column name.

   [image]
5. Copy & paste all choices on column settings page in **Type each choice on a separate line:** textbox

   [image]
6. Scroll to the bottom of column settings page --> Click **OK** to save changes

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked!